# Is it possible to use a Self Hosted Console Application as a Signal R Server if it is not publicly accessible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to run a self hosted C# console application that acts as a Signal R server that broadcasts to a ASP.NET MVC web application acting as a client at PokerConquest.com.

Whilst the website is publicly accessible.. does the server console application need to be publicly accessible? The communication will be one way (server to client). The self hosted console application can 'see' the outside world / make web requests etc.. it's just not publicly accessible.

All the samples you see online use localhost like this..

The server..

```
string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088";
var SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);
```

And the client..

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://127.0.0.1:8088/");
var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
```

which is great if your signal r servers and clients are on the same machine but a lot of the time they wont be..

So is it possible for a non publicly accessible self hosted console app to act as a signal r server and broadcast to a publicly accessible web app client?

Comment: You are looking at tutorials, these are usually explained from a debugging perspective. Therefor in the examples the server is localhost. (When you run a project in VS, it is run on the local PC not the server).

If you were to publish that code, it would not work on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signalr broadcasts are sent to clients that connect to the Signalr server (using Web Sockets or traditional AJAX).

If the clients cannot connect to the server, nothing will work.

Comment: Thanks, so both clients and server need to be publically accessible?

Comment: Would I be best using a different communication technology if Signal R relies on two way connectivity?

If I want to update the web ui (without page reload) from a self hosted console app what other technologies could I use? cross domain Ajax/JSON-P?

Comment: There is no way to push data to a client without that client connecting to your server.